# Jquery to upload multiple images and preview

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How would i be able to add to this script the ability to add multiple images like the following.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>jQuery Uploads</h1>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="file" id="imgInp" />
        <img id="target" src="#" alt="your image" />
        <input type="file" id="imgLarge1" />
        <img id="large1" src="#" alt="your image 1" />
        <input type="file" id="imgLarge2" />
        <img id="large2" src="#" alt="your image 2" />
    </form>
<script>
 function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();            
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#target').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know where to modify the jquery in order to allow for multiple images. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change your form a little:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="file" class="file" id="1"/>
        <img id="img1" src="#" alt="your image" />
        <input type="file" class="file" id="2"/>
        <img id="img2" src="#" alt="your image 1" />
        <input type="file" class="file" id="3"/>
        <img id="img3" src="#" alt="your image 2" />
</form>
```

and change the javascript to

```
function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();            
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#img'+e.id).attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $(".file").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what i was looking for, but not sure if this is normal, when i got to upload image2, it shows the preview and then pops up a window to upload again and it does it for image2 through image5, not sure why though

Comment: any idea on why this its opening up multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>jQuery Uploads</h1>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="file" id="imgInp"/>
        <img id="target_imgInp" src="#" alt="your image" class="thumb"/>
        <input type="file" id="large1" />
        <img id="target_large1" src="#" alt="your image 1" />
        <input type="file" id="large2" />
        <img id="target_large2" src="#" alt="your image 2" />
    </form>
<script>
 function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();            
            reader.onload = function (e) {

               $("#target_"+$(input).attr("id")).attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("input[type=file]").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
</script>
```